# Python regular expressions to match unicode code AND an actual character

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am trying to match this text to put a space in between the period & the quote marks after the word "Fraudsec"...

In Jupyter notebook

```
#to show the output version
text1 = """Mansotte came up with the idea for FraudSec.“I thought"""
text1 = text1.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
print text1
```

**Output**

"Mansotte came up with the idea for FraudSec.“I thought"

Also in Jupyter notebook

```
#to show the unicode version
text1
```

**Output**

"Mansotte came up with the idea for FraudSec.\u201cI thought, "

If I do...

```
re.sub(u'\u201c', u' ', text1)
```

I can replace the unicode reference with a space using the Unicode code point (\u201c)

**Output**

"Mansotte came up with the idea for FraudSec. I thought"

If I do...

```
re.sub(r'[.]', r' ', s)
```

I can replace the period character with a space

**Output**

"Mansotte came up with the idea for FraudSec \u201cI thought,"

**Problem I need help with**

I can't work out how to combine the 2 to match a character (period in this case) AND a Unicode code point ("\u201c" in this case).

**My failed guess**

```
re.sub(ur'([.])([A])', r'\1 \2', s)
```

something like this but I can't work out what to replace the "([A]) with to match the unicde. Everything I have tried comes back with a syntax error. Please help. :-)

Comment: There is no such thing as "raw text". A raw string literal treats backslashes differently but does nothing else special.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously I am a n00b and don't know the correct terms. Do you know the answer to my problem please?

Comment: Try this with back references: `re.sub(r'(?<=\.)(?=“)', ' ', text1)`

Comment: This might be oversimplifying things but did you try `print text1.replace('.“', '. “')`

Comment: It would but it's not scalable for my needs. I have dozens of Unicode code points (like '\u201c' in this example). I'm keen to learn if there is a way to a regex where the first part is the actual character and the second part is the code point.